# Static analysis tool groovyParser cannot scan console log output, please define a file pattern - Jenkins Warnings Next Generation Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

How to set the **Report File Pattern** with [Jenkins Warnings Next Generation Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Next+Generation+Plugin) when using a groovy parser as a post build action with static analysis tool (Report file pattern has to come for the empty input field in bellow image)

I have tried various methods but none of them worked. Appreciate any valuable input.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This parser examine **within the jenkins work space** of the project. Therefore when I gave a log file (or any other file type) in the workspace that worked properly. If anyone in the future came across with the same issue hope this could benefit you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This was logged as [JENKINS-54832](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-54832), which was resolved by adding a new "Permit Parsing of Console" option to the Jenkins Global Configuration. Users will need administrator access to the Jenkins server in order to take advantage of this feature though.